# In test runner cannot see tests in newly created folder - cypress

Tags: cypress

I created new folder 'apitests' in cypress project and created a JavaScript test file in it. It does not show up in the test runner.

I have used the default configuration in **cypress.json** as specified in [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files)

`"testFiles": "**/*.*",`

I expected my new folder 'apitests' and JavaScript test file to show in the test runner. Here is the end result.

[image]

Here is the file structure.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put your `apitests` folder directly in `cypress/`, while Cypress [by default](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test.html#Add-a-test-file) looks in `cypress/integration/` folder.

You can change that by using `integrationFolder` [config option](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files), but I'd personally just keep the spec files in `cypress/integration` as is the default.

Comment: Is there a way I can add multiple folders to the  `integrationFolder` ?  For example if I had multiple folders like 'apitests1' , 'apitests2', 'apitests3' with spec/test files in it  then  it would be nice to show only test files from specific folders, say just 'apitest2'  and 'apitests3'  folder only.

Comment: You can nest your specs arbitrarily, e.g. `integration/apitest1`,  `integration/apitest2`. You can filter/collapse folders in the cypress runner. If, instead, you just want to *run* a given folder(s), you can use `testFiles` config option (as of `3.6.0` can be an array of paths).

Answer (score -1):

I had to add this to `cypress.config.js`:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: [
      'cypress/e2e/*.js',
      'cypress/e2e/**/*.js'
    ]
  }
});
```

I had it initially, but removed it, to hope that Cypress would automatically find all my tests. But that resulted in new tests not being added to the test-runner.

**My Cypress-version:** `11.x.x` (and I updated to `12.0.2` as a debugging attempt).

The solution was found in the [Cypress-documentation for config](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#component).

Comment: The `'cypress/e2e/*.js'` pattern is covered by the `'cypress/e2e/**/*.js'` pattern, so it's just clutter. Hard to say what your answer actually is, Cypress 10+ still looks in the default folder `cypress/e2e` so it looks like you just had a transient moment with your test.

Comment: If I simply have the specPattern to be: `'cypress/e2e/*.js'`, then it can't find any tests. I apparently need: `'cypress/e2e/**/*.js'`... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Nope, you got it backwards, and `cypress/e2e/**/*.js` is the default as Sariget says.

Answer (score -2):

You've put your apitests folder directly in cypress/, while Cypress by default looks in cypress/integration/ folder.
[You will get an idea about it](https://webautomationtool.blogspot.com/2021/05/test-files-sequence-in-cypress.html)